# Pseudo R squared for cumulative link function

Tags: r, ordinal

I have an ordinal dependent variable and trying to use a number of independent variables to predict it. I use `R`. The function I use is `clm` in the `ordinal` package, to perform a cumulative link function with a probit link, to be precise:

I tried the function `pR2` in the package `pscl` to get the pseudo R squared with no success.

How do I get pseudo R squareds with the `clm` function?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible minimal example including data and code.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of pseudo-R^2. I don't like to use any of them because I do not see the results as having a meaning in the real world. They do not estimate effect sizes of any sort and they are not particularly good for statistical inference. Furthermore in situations like this with multiple observations per entity, I think it is debatable which value for "n" (the number of subjects) or the degrees of freedom is appropriate.  Some people use McFadden's R^2 which would be relatively easy to calculate, since `clm` generated a list with one of its values named "logLik". You just need to know that the logLikelihood is only a multiplicative constant (-2)  away from the deviance. If one had the model in the first example:

```
 library(ordinal)
data(wine)
fm1 <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
fm0 <- clm(rating ~ 1, data = wine)
( McF.pR2 <- 1 - fm1$logLik/fm0$logLik )
[1] 0.1668244
```

I had seen this question on CrossValidated and was hoping to see the more statistically sophisticated participants over there take this one on, but they saw it as a programming question and dumped it over here. Perhaps their opinion of R^2 as a worthwhile measure is as low as mine?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use function nagelkerke from rcompanion package to get Pseudo r-squared.

When your predictor or outcome variables are categorical or ordinal, the R-Squared will typically be lower than with truly numeric data. R-squared merely a very weak indicator about model's fit, and you can't choose model based on this.